# How can I make google chrome ask permission to run javascript on a website?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, settings

I can enable or disable javascript for any given web site.
I can change the global default permissions for javascript to be enable or disable.

I want a third choice, namely a global default permission for javascript of "ask".

When this is chosen, visiting a website I haven't been to before would give me a popup saying "Allow javascript for this website?" with options such as "Once, Always, Not this time, Never"

Is this possible, perhaps with a flag?
Or, do I need to install an extension?

I visited chrome://settings/content/javascript
I hoped to see three different options.
Instead, what I actually saw was "Sites can use Javascript" and "Don't allow sites to use Javascipt".

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is a browser extesion. For example, NoScript is a popular one.